# android recyclerview divider in custom text

Tags: android, text, kotlin, android-recyclerview, divider

We are implementing the list through Recyclerview.

I would like to display the time in the Divider by putting text in it.

No matter how I try to find it, I can search for the solution to the problem and leave a question.

Please refer to the screenshot below.

Help!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create an item_view.xml (give enough bottom padding) for your adapter. Create a TextView for your time entry, bind in your adapter to display.